# Java RMI registry can't find server object

Tags: java, server, rmi, rmiregistry

So, the problem is I have some server code that will allow a Client to call functions on it using rmiregistry. It should be noted I'm running these commands on OS X terminal and I have two folders I'm working within:

`RMI` - which will call the rmiregistry and 
`Server` - which has all my server code in it

So, I open one terminal and enter this:

```
rmiregistry -J-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/Desktop/RMI/Server/ &
```

All is well, I get a port back.
I then login to the Server folder that contains my server code to run my `calculatorserver` program. 
Now I've been told to specify the codebase and the security policy:

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/Desktop/RMI/Server/ -Djava.security.policy=server.policy calculatorserver
```

However, I keep on getting this same error:

```
Server Error: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: calculator
```

I know the only reason I'm getting this error is because the rmiregistry can't find the server object.

Some guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a real HTTP URL. It's a directory name with `http:` stuck in front of it. You need to use a real `http:` URL with a real HTTP server. Or FTP.

You can use a `file:` URL, but then you're more or less stuck within a single host, in which case you don't actually need the codebase feature at all. And if you do use a `file:` URL, it has to be intelligible to the Registry and the client, which again means either they're all in the same host or it names a shared directory that the Registry and client can see.

NB Don't specify the codebase to the Registry (or the client, unless it exports remote (callback) objects): only to the server JVM

Comment: My mistake, I had it down as a 'file:' URL - pasted the wrong clipboard. Which is what I want. What exactly do mean by specifying the codebase to the server JVM?

Comment: 'Specifying the codebase' = `-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=...`. You should only specify that argument to the server JVM, or more generally to JVMs that export remote objects that need the codebase. The Registry isn't one of those.